# FlashBuilder4 RIA on GAE

Tags: java, apache-flex, spring, flash-builder

I want to build a highly scalable "facebook for business" and after much testing am pretty set on FlashBuilder4 (Flex) with Google App Engine (GAE).

What are your thoughts on the need/advisability of also using Spring/Cairngorm/etc frameworks?

Frankly I don't have extensive experience coding, however feel the "MVC utopia" universally aspired to becomes convoluting when duplicating between front and back ends as envisioned above (i.e. Flex/ActionScript and GAE/Java respectively).

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of using a framework is that the long-term maintenance of your application is more easily done because you have coded consistently with specific standards.  You can also have multiple developers working in parallel and easily "piece" the parts back together if they are done consistently.

At least that is part of the promise frameworks provide, in theory.

A framework is built to solve a specific problem in development.  Before choosing a framework, you should review your application and decide if a framework will help you solve those problems.  If it can great; if it can't you shouldn't force your app to use a framework.

If you are duplicating a lot of code between the front and back end, that seems problematic to me.  I'm not surprised that value objects would be mirrored between the front and back end, but their whole purpose is transferring data between different systems.  Other code, or business logic, should ideally only exist in one system.

As an aside; What an oddly phrased question.  If you read specific blogs of experts and want their opinions, why are you posting here instead of contacting them directly?

Comment: First thanks for the response, second this is where the blogger directed questions to be posted and third (while I have your attention), I have "narrowed" my framework attention to testing webORB for Java (http://www.themidnightcoders.com/products/weborb-for-java/overview.html).  As you suggest it seems to promise less coding and more transferability (plus added proprietary web services) albeit with an price at the Enterprise level. 
 
Do you have any thoughts to add and/or direct experience with WebORB (or even Spring/etc)?

Comment: I am a fan of WebORB.  I used it mainly for AMF remoting on .NET. There is a code generator piece, which can help with less coding. But I don't consider WebORB a framework.  I don't know too much about Java frameworks, such as Spring.

Comment: I've edited the question to make it more generally directed.  As I said on my blog "Please make sure that questions asked on StackOverflow are for a general developer audience, ie. something that more people than just you want to know the answer to. If your question is specific to you then email is still the best way to ask me."

Answer (score 0):

The combination of Flex and GAE can be very powerful.  However GAE does have limitations that may impact what you are trying to build.  For instance GAE doesn't support Spring last time I checked.  Another cloud alternative that may work better is the new partnership between VMWare (SpringSource) and Salesforce.com called [VMforce](http://www.vmforce.com/).